# Transfer retail Office licenses from purchased PCs

Tags: windows, microsoft-office-2007, license

My company has purchased the asserts of another which includes several workstations with Microsoft Office Professional 2007. Install DVDs were included in the purchase and they are retail versions from Amazon and BestBuy.

Can we simply uninstall Office on the acquired computers and use the install DVDs on our existing PCs without concern of license violations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends and you have not given enough information.

If they were retail copies then the answer is yes.

If they were licensed copies on some sort of licensing plan which the company purchased, and you purchased that license (in its entirety) from them, then I believe there was a recent legal battle where it was shown it is legal and ok to do so.

If they were OEM editions, the answer is no as they are tied to the machine they are installed on.

Comment: thanks, I've updated my question and they are retail versions.